# Sunday as a Week Marker

Tags: meaning, word-usage, dates

When someone uses the phrase "the week of the [Sunday's date]" does that usually refer to the week preceding that Sunday or after it?

Comment: What’s your guess, and why?

Comment: Well, I've seen it used both ways so I don't know which is more conventional.  I would personally prefer to use it to specify the coming week, with Sunday being the first day.

Comment: I’d say the fact that you’ve seen both is quite indicative: since some people and some places consider Sunday the first day of the week, and others consider it the last day of the week, there really is no ‘usually’ about it. It depends entirely on the people using it. People should just name weeks by Mondays instead—at least you’ll always know what week you’re talking about, then!

Comment: Different societies and subsections within society think of the week as starting on different days, but I don't think I've *ever* come across a context where anyone has used *the week of [some date]* to mean *the seven days **ending** on that date*. Rarely, someone might say *the week of the 5th February* (a Wednesday) to mean *the "standard" 7-day week which **includes** that date*. But in the unlikely event that person thought of weeks as starting on Thursday, they'd almost certainly say *the week **ending** on 5th February*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sunday is the first day of the week, so it is the days after it.

And if the person lives in a place that starts weeks on some other day, then it is very unlikely that Sunday will be used to mark the week.  Instead, you would give Monday's date when saying "The Week of March Xth", never the date of the last day of said week.

Comment: Then why do all the European calendars have Monday as the first day of the week?

Comment: Sunday is traditionally the first day of the week _in the Anglosphere_. Only South Africa, Canada, the US, and Mexico (by US influence, I suspect) officially retain this. The UK officially follows EU policy and has the first day of the week as Monday, but many Brits still consider it to be Sunday. In most of the rest of the world, it is Monday (and some places in the Middle East it is Saturday). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-day_week#Week_numbering) has a clear overview of the differences.

Comment: What @JanusBahsJacquet said. To further complicate matters, some large companies in the USA work on a "fiscal calendar" that starts the week on Monday. So honestly, in English most likely the days *after* Sunday were what was meant, but you really ought to ask to be sure.

Comment: @tchrist  I imagine most European calendars aren't in English and thus don't have any Mondays.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I have heard you say this before. But let it be known that I was born and bred in Britain and have lived here for 63 of my 69 years, and you are the first person who has ever pointed out to me that 'the UK' (whoever that means) recognises that the week starts on a Monday. All the printed diaries and calendars show it as Sunday, and always have done. When I lived temporarily in Japan it seemed odd seeing the first day shown as Monday.

Comment: @WS2 weeks do indeed officially start on Mondays in the UK for quite a few purposes. This is also true of the US. It's pretty inconsequential though, because who gives a damn when the official start of the week is except calendar nerds (and all we're going to do is write comments like this one about it), the calendar police aren't going to kick down anyone's doors.

Comment: @JonHanna What are these nefarious 'purposes'? Are we talking about the DWP or anything like that? The calendar on my Blackberry does have the weeks starting on Mondays, but I assumed that was just the international influence. Why have I never seen a printed calendar with Monday shown as the start of the week?

Comment: @WS2 any where there's a need to agree on what week number you are in. British Standard BS ISO 8601:2004 (and BS EN 28601 still current in some uses) say the week starts on Monday, so that's when week 17 becomes week 18. There aren't many printed calendars with Monday (though I have seen some in the UK) because that's not the convention commonly used.

Comment: @JonHanna It wouldn't any longer be Britain if we accepted any change wholeheartedly. Even the metric system is not complete. Thankfully you can still buy a pint of ale and get pints of milk delivered by the milkman. And long may it remain so!

Comment: @WS2 not really, the conventional use and standardised use meet different needs, and to someone like myself who likes precision when it helps me and tradition when it doesn't hurt, I'm glad I can buy a pint of ale and consumer laws mean it'll be the mandated 568ml (now getting a US pint would be a tragedy). I do wish the UK would get rid off the quaint use of miles and miles per hour on the road, where it is a genuine nuisance to pretend the M25 is part of a Renaissance Faire or something.

Comment: @JonHanna I don't know what the cost of changing the road signs and everything else ( and I suspect there is a lot of 'everything else') would be, but you can be sure it would be numbered in billions. And what would the payback be? Zilch! We are not like the French who seem unconstrained by the need to demonstrate payback. They just do things for the glory of France, like upgrading all their rail track to take TGV at a cost which will never be paid back in the lifetime of anyone currently living.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12841/discussion-between-jon-hanna-and-ws2)

Answer (score 1):

My own convention and that which is standard in the UK is to say either 'Week commencing 10th February', or 'week ending 16th February', where 10th is Sunday and 16th is Saturday. These are abbreviated as follows;

w/c 10/2/14
w/e 16/2/14

Both refer to the same week.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunday),

> For most observant Christians, Sunday is observed as a day of worship
>   and rest, holding it as the Lord's Day and the day of Christ's
>   resurrection.
>
> In some China countries and Israel, Sunday is the first
>   work day of the week.
>
> According to the Hebrew calendar and traditional
>   Christian calendars, Sunday is the first day of the week.
>
> But
>   according to the International Organization for Standardization ISO
>   8601, Sunday is the seventh day of the week.

This means that there isn't universal agreement about whether Sunday is the first or last day of a week. Different people adopt different stances.

This means that people will not agree about whether a Sunday 'belongs' in the 7 day period finishing on that Sunday or starting on that Sunday. (Some might even want a Wednesday-Tuesday 'week', cf the financial year.)

The phrase 'the week of the 24th' (being a Sunday) is, as OP suggests in a comment, correspondingly ambiguous. Though it is likely that few would use just an end date to define a week.

Answer (score 0):

According to what I discovered on Google search,  and from my own personal experience living and working in Germany:

"Monday is the beginning of the week in German-speaking countries, just like the rest of Europe. The most important Monday in Germany has got to be Rosenmontag, which is on the Monday before Ash Wednesday." -on Sep 14, 2018

Comment: I'm not sure that this actually answers the question.

Comment: Is that a quote? You need to add a link and attribution. Does 'the rest of Europe' still include the UK? //  Is the situation the same in other Anglophone countries?